# regex in java, making a search for particular string pattern?

Tags: java, regex

i am not much familiar with regex expressions use in Java.
If i have a String `this/is/a/file!/path`

now with `substring` and `indexOf` i can find the name file appearing inbetween `/` and `!` but i am pretty sure such tasks must be much easier using regexes.

Can someone give me an example for doing so using regex expressions?

Comment: For this problem, your approach is the simplest yet the fastest. Don't think of RegEx unless you want to read something apart from the `file` part of the string.

Comment: Google is your friend. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: @adarshr: How would you do this without regex?  Seems to me it's just complicated enough that regex *is* the simplest way.

Comment: @AlanMoore, something like this: http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/4510/searchzy.png

Comment: Yeah, that's about the best I could come up with, too.  The regex approach is shorter *and* easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is to use Pattern and Matcher. Here you can use groups and more complex operations

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(yourRegex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourText);
while(matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Take a look at

Matcher : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Pattern : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Regex in Java : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 0):

somthing as `.*/([^!]*)!.*` should do this... then you can use a matcher to find the 1st group (the part between parenthesis, the 0th group is the whole match)

I didn't test this solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Pattern Object with a regular expression and then create a matcher object from it to parse your String.

```
String regex = ".*/(.*)!";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile (regex);

Matcher m = p.matcher(StringToBeMatched);

if (m.find()) {

    String filename = m.group (1);
}
```

Comment: You didn't test this solution, did you?  The code is correct, but that regex won't even compile.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way of using them in Java is by using the `String.matches` method:

```
boolean matches = "abc".matches("[a-z]+");
```

That would yield `true`.

The second way of doing it is useful if you have to use a specific regex pattern a lot of times. You can compile it and reuse it:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("abc");
boolean matches = matcher.matches();
```

Comment: String.matches would only match the entire string. The question refers to extracting a matching substring of the path.